# When I save a Object I cannot load from task

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm using Objectify to save and load to Datastore.

When I save a object using:

```
ObjectDto newObjDto = new ObjectDto(/*some data*/);
ofy().save().entity(newObjDto).now();
Long newID = postDto.getId(); //new saved ID, field marked as @Id
```

Then I start immediately a task using `newID` as task parameter, to do some operations about new object, but I cannot load from task:

```
Long obj_id = Long.parseLong(p_request.getParameter("obj_id"));
//obj_id is valid id
ObjectDto objDto = ofy().load().type(ObjectDto.class).id(obj_id).now(); 
//but at this point  objDto = null   .... why?
```

What I'm do wrong?

There is need to wait some time?

Comment: Datastore's `get` operations are always consistent, so there is no need to wait. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your code for this: _"Then I start immediately a task using newID as task parameter"_ ?

Comment: There is a @Parent annotation to one field, when I comment that works fine... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use @Parent, you get the object using ancestor.

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AdvancedPatterns